# Best Practices for Writing SAS Documentation?

Tags: sas

I'm looking for a style guide to writing documentation for SAS software.

Looking at docs for, say, procedures, there seems to be a common method of writing about them. For example, in this PDF book on procedures for Base 9.2, http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/PDF/default/proc.pdf , all the procs seem to be explained in an (overview, syntax, concepts, results, examples) format. I can work this out by example, but if I do, I'll likely miss key things like spelling conventions. Ideally I'd like to see a best practices guide for writing this sort of documentation, if one exists.

My goal is to write a SAS equivalent to this article, which is a support of the best practices for R documentation: http://www.stats-et-al.com/2019/04/writing-r-documentation-simplified.html

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or advise me towards some key examples?

Comment: Guide for writing documentation for SAS software?  Who will be your audience for this article?  Because SAS is not open-source, and all documentation is written by people who work at SAS, who have their own rules.

Comment: @AlexK Not so -- in the strong sense that SAS users can write up their own extra code, whether publicly released or made available only within a workplace or to selected individuals. Even open source software may be written for private use, so the implication of a sharp division is unfounded here. (I bail out on answering, as I have never used SAS.)

Comment: @NickCox, yes, thanks, I agree, I should have specified that official documentation for SAS software is written by the company SAS.

Comment: Strictly it's more complicated than that even. For example, books published by SAS have often been written by non-employees. To what extent that is "official" is a matter for a company definition.

Comment: Seems OT for S.O.  "Best Practices" are opinions, and not really a programming question.  It's still a good question. Maybe try posting at communities.sas.com.